# How does return work in monad-transformer Context?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

found the below snippet for monad transformers from [Monad Transformers](https://mmhaskell.com/monads/transformers)

```
main3 :: IO ()
main3 = do
  maybeCreds <- runMaybeT $ do
    usr <- readUserName'
    debugFunc usr
    email <- readEmail'
    debugFunc email
    pass <- readPassword'
    debugFunc pass
    return (usr, email, pass)
  case maybeCreds of
    Nothing -> print "Couldn't login!"
    Just (u, e, p) -> login u e p
```

Each of the functions readUserName, readPassword and readEmail have the type MaybeT IO String

I am  not able to understand how  `return (usr, email, pass)`  works. Shouldn't there be a conflict because it is not a String and instead a tuple.

Comment: Nop, the type of `return (usr, email, pass)` is `MaybeT IO (String, String, String)`, so theres no conflict.

Comment: All the actions in the same do block must work in the same monad. In your case the monad is `MaybeT IO`, so each actions must have a type of the form `MaybeT IO T`, but `T` can vary from action to action. Indeed, in the same IO block we want to be able to run `a <- readLn :: IO Int` and `b <- getLine :: IO String`, for instance.

Comment: `return (usr, email, pass)` is equivalent to `MaybeT (return (Just ()usr, email, pass))` where `return` in the second code fragment is `return :: a -> IO a`.

Comment: Each of the actions `debugFunc usr`, `debugFunc email`, and `debugFunc pass` have the type `MaybeT IO ()`. Does it concern you that `()` is not `String`? Why (not)?